# Proving a claim about a recurrence

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I have a recurrence that is defined as follows
$$
T(n,m)=
\begin{cases}
2&\text{if } n=0 \text{ or } m=0\\
T(n-1,m)+T(n,m-1)+2& \text{if } n,m\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
where $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. I'm supposed to prove that
$$
T(n,n)\geq 2^n
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I'm just having trouble understanding how to do the proof because there's two variables. I think I want to prove with strong induction that (this is my inductive hypothesis)
$$
T(k+1,k+1)\geq 2^{k+1}
$$
where $k\geq 2$ is an integer. But I get stuck, and I think that means it's because maybe my claim is incorrect or there's something i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Fist let's notice that $\forall \, n,m \geq 0,\, T(n,m) > 0 $.

Then, if you have $k \geq 2 $ such that
$$ T(k,k) \geq 2^k . $$
from
$$ T(k+1,k+1) = T(k,k+1) + T(k+1,k) + 2. $$
Applying the defining recurrence once again on every term you get
$$ T(k+1,k+1) = T(k-1,k+1) + 2 \,T(k,k) + T(k+1,k-1) + 6 \geq 2 \, T(k,k) \geq 2^{k+1} .$$
I'll let you check for $k=1$ and $k=0$

Answer (score 0):

At the first step of the recursion you are adding 2, in the second step you are adding 4 because there are two sub-recursive steps. In the third step you'll add 8 and so on.

When computing $T(n, n)$ we need at least $n$ steps until one of the coordinates becomes zero, and at each of those steps we'll be adding some power of $2$, giving us a sum $2+2^2+\dots+2^n = 2^{n+1}-2 > 2^n$.

As an example:
$$\begin{align*}
T(3, 3) &= 2+T(2, 3)+T(3, 2)\\
&= 2+(2+2)+T(1, 3)+T(2,2)+T(2, 2)+T(3, 1)\\
&= 2+4+(2+2+2+2)+\dots\\
&\geq 14
\end{align*}$$
(this requires first showing that $T$ is always nonnegative, which is obvious).